# Magento 2 Downloadable Product and Gift Product are not visible in Sales Order Grid Page

Tags: magento2, database, downloadable, order-details

I am facing issue on **Downloadable Product** in **Magento2 Sales Order Grid Page** back end.When Customer placed order for Downloadable Product say (EBOOK) where its not available in `Admin->sales` order grid.

**Magento Version : 2.1.13**

I have checked in **Magento DB - Sales Order Grid** and the record was there but its not displaying under **Sales Grid Table**.

Also If I use **entity_id** in the **order detail page** URL where I can able to view see the **order details** successfully.

Please do assist what was the issue and why its not displaying under **grid table**.

Also can u please tell where i can fetch grid order collection data and query code behind it.